# Converting subset of strings to integers in a list

Tags: python

I frequently find myself with a list that looks like this:

```
lst = ['A', '1', '2', 'B', '1', 'C', 'D', '4', '1', '4', '5', 'Z', 'D']
```

What is the most pythonic way to convert specific strings in this list to ints?

I typically do something like this:

```
lst = [lst[0], int(lst[1]), int(lst[2]), lst[3], ...]
```

The above approach seems wrong. Are there better way to convert only certain items in lists to integers?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would say something like:

```
>>> lst = ['A', '1', '2', 'B', '1', 'C', 'D', '4', '1', '4', '5', 'Z', 'D']
>>> lst = [int(s) if s.isdigit() else s for s in lst]
>>> lst
['A', 1, 2, 'B', 1, 'C', 'D', 4, 1, 4, 5, 'Z', 'D']
```

Comment: Can this be applied to floats as well? I couldn't find a corresponding `isfloat()` method.

Comment: For more general purpose you could write either a regex to match or do like @JFSebastian did and wrap the conversion in a try/except block in a utility function.

Answer (score 5):

`int` and `.isdigit` can disagree in Unicode case i.e., `int` might fail to parse a string even if `.isdigit` returns `True` for the string.

```
def maybe_int(s):
    try:
        return int(s)
    except ValueError:
        return s

lst = [maybe_int(s) for s in lst]
```

Answer (score 0):

@FatalError answer is probably what you are looking for, but if you want to just convert some items(not all the numbers) to integer you could do something like this:

```
>>> lst = ['A', '1', '2', 'B', '1', 'C', 'D', '4', '1', '4', '5', 'Z', 'D']
>>> indices = [1,2]
>>> [int(lst[x]) if x in indices else lst[x] for x in xrange(len(lst))]
['A', 1, 2, 'B', '1', 'C', 'D', '4', '1', '4', '5', 'Z', 'D']
```